# jQuery setTimeout on first click then clearTimeout on second

Tags: jquery, animation, settimeout

The first time a user clicks a button I want there to be a 3 second timeout set on a div before it is loop animated.

If the user then clicks a second time during that 3 seconds, I want the timeout to clear and the animation to stop.

So far I can get the timeout to work fine but I can't clear it and get the animation to stop.

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
<div class="block"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.block {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: red; }
```

The jQuery:

```
$('a.button').toggle(function(){
    var blockTimer;
    blockTimer = setTimeout(function block(){
      $("div.block").animate({top: '400px'}, 4000, 'linear', function() { $(this).css('top', '-10px'); block(); });
        },3000);
}, function(){
clearTimeout(rainTimer);
    $('div.block').clearQueue().stop().fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).css('top', '-10px').show(); });
});
```

Comment: please make a js fiddle of problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the variable *outside* of the scope of the function so that you can clear it later on. Also, you're clearing `rainTimer`, yet you're defining it as `blockTimer`.

```
var blockTimer;

$('a.button').toggle(function(){
    blockTimer = setTimeout(function block() {
        $("div.block").animate({top: '400px'}, 4000, 'linear', function() { $(this).css('top', '-10px'); block(); });
        }, 3000);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(blockTimer);
    $('div.block').clearQueue().stop().fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).css('top', '-10px').show(); });
});
```

Comment: Ah yes of course! It seems so obvious now. Sorry I typed rainTimer by mistake, I had it correct in my original code. This answer is correct though.